# Telerik OpenAccess ORM - return types for queries

Tags: c#, orm, telerik

Is there a way to change the return type for queries generated by OpenAccess?  The default return type is Object[], but I need it to be a specific type that was generated by the ORM.

Comment: Never mind. I thought I couldn't edit the autogenerated code b/c it would be regenerated on every build.  But it looks like it allows edits after initial creation.  So I just changed the return type.

Comment: The best thing to do here would be to post your solution as the answer to your own question.  That's perfectly acceptable on SO, and adds to the overall knowledge of the site for someone to find later.

Comment: @alwayslearning has the correct (and evidently only) answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are referring to the code generated to execute a stored procedure. This method, in the generated context class, is regenerated every time you save the domain model (.rlinq file). In case you want to modify the return type you can create a partial class for the context and add the method there.

Regarding the question - how do you change the return type of the generated method? Currently this is not supported via the designer but work on a detailed UI for stored procedures, is ongoing. The next service pack would most probably have a UI where you can choose an existing persistent type as the return value or you can generate a CLR type which maps to the returned result.